# inline variable assign in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, inline, variable-assignment

I googled a lot on this and didn't get any useful results, I'm trying to declare a variable inline, in C# it works as follows:

```
int x, y;
x = 5 + (y = 6) + 7;
```

which will assign **y=6** and **x=18** and if used right, allows you to do some crazy things in one line.

And my question is, how to do it in JS? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only modification required is switching `int` to `var`

```
var x, y;
x = 5 + (y = 6) + 7;
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/RP4Dj/

Comment: Oh my. That's me, too much googling, not enough trying. Thank you.

Comment: @user2359063: Read a beginner's tutorial, and these simple problems will be solved. Hard to believe that after all the googling you supposedly did, you didn't find one example of how to properly declare a variable in JavaScript.

Comment: Years later coming back to clarify. The reason my googling didn't bear any results was the sole fact that I was unable to define the search term properly. Even today, when I enter this question's title into Google, I don't get much.